# A single MySQL statement to JOIN table and do some calculations

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables called "book" and "setting_category". I would like to join them together and create a new field call "final_price" by sample calculation for the result.

How can I use a single MySQL statement to do that?

**I have tried but not a single statement:**

```
SELECT * FROM setting_category JOIN book ON book.cate_id =
setting_category.cate_id WHERE cate_name = 'Fiction'

SELECT * , (CASE WHEN special_offer_type = 'Fixed Value' THEN price -
special_offer WHEN special_offer_type = 'Discount %' THEN price * (1 -
(special_offer /100)) END) AS final_price FROM book
```

book

```
book_id cate_id book_name   price   special_offer   special_offer_type      
1       1       AAA         125     5               FixedValue      
2       1       BBB         90      30              Discount%       
3       2       CCC         150     50              FixedValue
```

setting_category

```
cate_id cate_name                       
1       Fiction                     
2       Dictionary
```

result_table

```
book_id cate_id book_name   price   special_offer   special_offer_type  cate_name       final_price
1       1       AAA         125         5           FixedValue          Fiction         120
2       1       BBB         90          30          Discount%           Fiction         63
3       2       CCC         150         50          FixedValue          Dictionary      100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `case` statement for the calculation:

```
select b.*, sc.cate_name,
       (case when special_offer_type = 'FixedValue'
             then b.price - b.special_offer
             when special_offer_type = 'Discount%'
             then b.price * (1 - b.special_offer/100.0)
             else b.price
        end) as final_price
from book b join
     setting_category sc
     on b.cate_id = sc.cate_id;
```

Comment: THX Gordon

I got an error

`#1054 - Unknown column 'sc.special_offer' in 'field list'`

Comment: @user3453786 . . . That's because `special_offer` appears to be in the `book` table.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to combine them is to pull out all the fields you want from both tables (t1.fieldA, t1.fieldB, t2.fieldC, etc) and then make a field like you just did with your case statement. So it would look something like this:

```
SELECT
     (CASE WHEN t1.special_offer_type = 'Fixed Value' THEN t1.price - t1.special_offer WHEN t1.special_offer_type = 'Discount %' THEN t1.price * (1 - (t1.special_offer /100)) END) AS final_price,
     t1.book_id,
     t1.book_name,
FROM
     book t1
JOIN
     setting_category t2
 ON
     t1.cate_id = t2.cate_id
 WHERE
     t2.WHERE cate_name = 'Fiction';
```

Comment: Please include some explanation to be more educative.

Comment: @LaszloPapp yea I thought about that after I posted it.. thanks for keeping me honest :P